# Create a div with a cross and a text inside with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div with an 'x' and a text inside it, as shown on this image

[image]

Can I somehow improve this snippet?

```css
div {
   width:49px;
   height:49px; 
   border:1px solid black;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:49px;
   font-size:25px;
}
div:before {
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   width:0;
   height:0;   
   top:-1px;
   left:-1px;
   border:25px solid transparent;
   border-right:25px solid black;
   border-bottom:25px solid black;
   z-index:-3;
}
div:after {
   position:absolute;
   content:'';
   width:0;
   height:0;
   top:1px;
   left:1px;
   border:24px solid transparent;
   border-right:24px solid white;
   border-bottom:24px solid white;
   z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<div>XL</div>
```

The snippet above is just what I've done so far, a completely different solution(as long as the outcome is as shown on the image attached) is perfectly fine

Comment: Does your HTML need to be the same as your example?

Comment: @metaDesign, no, the HTML can also be different than a single div

Comment: @DaemonPainter I attached an image of the desired outcome, maybe you can't see it?

Comment: @Andy and does it need to have a transparent background?

Comment: @metaDesign no, I think that it could work even with a standard white (#fff) background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure the text is always centered in the div, you could use `absolute` positioning and apply a `background`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogLtpxw0/3/)

```css
.wrapper {
   width:50px;
   height:50px; 
   border:2px solid black;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:25px;
   padding: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper:before {
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left: 50%;
   width:0;
   height:200%;   
   border: 1px solid black;
   transform: translateY(-50%)rotate(45deg);
   z-index: -3;
}
.wrapper:after {
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left: 50%;
   width:0;
   height:200%;   
   border: 1px solid black;
   transform: translateY(-50%)rotate(-45deg);
   z-index: -3;
}
.wrapper > div {
   background: #fff;
   padding: 5px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    XL
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use linear-gradient()

I made two choices, inspired by the answers.

I used linear-gradient (), which is another way.

```css
.first,
.second {
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 8px auto;
  line-height: 49px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.first:before,
.second:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 142%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -3;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #333, #333 25%, #eee0 25%, #eee0 75%, #333 75%);
  padding: 0.5px;
}

.first:after,
.second:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 142%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: -3;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #333, #333 25%, #eee0 25%, #eee0 75%, #333 75%);
  padding: 0.5px;
}

.second {
  width: 68px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.second:after {
  height: 172%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-54deg);
}

.second:before {
  height: 172%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(54deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">XL</div>
<div class="second">XL</div>
```

Comment: I really like this solution too, looks clean

Answer (score 0):

wrap your text on a `span` tag, add `background`

```css
div {
   width:49px;
   height:49px; 
   border:1px solid black;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:49px;
   font-size:25px;
}
div span{
   background:#fff;
}
div:before {
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   width:0;
   height:0;   
   top:-1px;
   left:-1px;
   border:25px solid transparent;
   border-right:25px solid black;
   border-bottom:25px solid black;
   z-index:-3;
}
div:after {
   position:absolute;
   content:'';
   width:0;
   height:0;
   top:1px;
   left:1px;
   border:24px solid transparent;
   border-right:24px solid white;
   border-bottom:24px solid white;
   z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<div><span>XL</span></div>
```